# How to show that $A_n$ generated by all permutations of the form (ab)(cd)?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I need to show that if n $\ge$ 5 then $A_n$ generated by all permutations of the form (ab)(cd) (a b c d are all different)

Can I use the fact that union of conjugacy classes is normal ?

Its clear that $\sigma$(ab)(cd)$\sigma$ = ($\sigma$(a)$\sigma$(b))($\sigma$(c)$\sigma$(d)), 
it's suffices to say that the group $\lt$ e , $\lbrace$ (ab)(cd) | a b c d are all different $\rbrace$  $\gt$ generates $A_n$?

Comment: Comment: $a\neq b\neq c\neq d$ does not exclude $a=c$ or $b=d$.

Comment: I meant :  a b c and d are all different numbers

Comment: The simplest way to express that is probably $\#\{a,b,c,d\}=4$.

Comment: Have you proved that $A_n$ is generated by all three-cycles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a permutation in $A_n$, write it as the product of an even number of transpositions.  Break these into pairs, consecutively.  Each pair of transpositions is necessarily of one of the following three types:

1. $(a b) (a b)$
2. $(a b) (b c)$
3. $(a b) (c d)$

Ignore the first type.  The third type are of the kind you're given, and rewrite the second type as $(a b) (b c) =[(a b) (d e)] [(b c) (d e)]$, the product of two of the kind you're given.  You need $n\ge 5$ to always have two spare elements to use in this way.

Comment: Very nice ! But still can I use the fact that every conjugacy classes is normal ? And the fact that $A_n$ is simple group ? (for n > 4)

Comment: @Saar peer: If you know that $A_n$ is simple, then in fact this implies the original claim. However, whether you are allowed to use this in your situation, I cannot tell (it may be the case that you are using the claim as part of a proof that $A_n$ is simple).